# Cannot create/join homegroup on my network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, home-networking, homegroup

I have a computer running windows 8.1.

I had previously created a homegroup on my computer, and updated to Windows 10. I reverted back to Windows 8.1, and was no longer a member of the homegroup I had previously created.

When I try joining that homegroup, it says 'This homegroup no longer exists'.

No other PC's on the network see this homegroup. When I open 'Control Panel/HomeGroup' I see this:

[image: homegroup exists]

Then, when I click Join - I get this series:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I enter the password, and then...

[image]

I have tried removing all the PeerNetworking files, restarting the HomeGroup and PeerNetworking services, rebooting, etc. Nothing seems to work.

**EDIT**

I also tried renaming my computers Computer Name in the system settings, that did not work either.

**/EDIT**

Does anyone have ANY other suggestion other than what I have found on the net so far?

Answer (score 0):

Source: [www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/win-10-homegroup-issues/](http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/win-10-homegroup-issues/)

1. Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\`
2. Rename *MachineKeys* folder to *MachineKeys-OLD*
3. Create a new folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`
4. Right click the MachineKeys folder and select Properties and click Security tab
5. Highlight *Everyone*, click Edit then set Full Control permissions to *Everyone*
6. Restart

This worked for me